# QGIS Add Raster Values to Points Turns up Null Values

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to add raster values to points with QGIS 3.2. When the command runs the result is a column with null values. I also tried the same thing with the Point Sampling Tool with the same result. Both my vector point layer and my raster underlying layer are in the same CRS: NAD 5070.

Any ideas on what I might be missing?

[image: Add raster value to points attempt]

Comment: When you run the "Add raster values to points", on the second tab there is the algorithm's log. Can you share the log?

Comment: Are all the values null? Or just some of them?